# Canceling a credit card with recurring/automatic payments

Tags: credit-card, charity, donation

I am canceling a credit card because I am extremely unhappy with the bank. I have several recurring pledges and donations linked to this card.

Do I need to contact each organization individually and change to a different card? Is there some more automatic or bulk means to 'redirect' charges to my new card?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry; you'll need to contact each organization and provide new credit card information.  (Ideally, you should have done this before canceling your card.)

Unfortunately, there's no easy or "bulk" way to do what you seek, unless you used a single intermediary (e.g. PayPal) in the first place – and that's not an approach I would recommend due to fees and other potential issues.

I've been through this process twice before – once for having cancelled an account, and once because my account number was changed due to credit card fraud – and contacting each organization having a recurring payment was a necessary hassle each time.  :-/

But, I did find one way to save time:  My approach was to handle anything considered a *bill* myself and as soon as possible, so a payment wouldn't be declined and potentially harm my credit.  I either called each vendor by phone or used their secure web site, when possible.

Since I wanted to minimize my time on the phone or writing letters, for *charities* I decided to let them get around to requesting my new account details.  Each quickly noticed a declined payment and wrote to me to request updated account information.  I just had to fill in whatever form was provided and send it back, which saved me time.  Many of them have a streamlined process for this because credit cards expire all the time.  Still, if you want to save them the hassle, the letter, and the stamp, then do call.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you really should first either cancel or change the donations to a new card. I got a bill once for a recurring charge on a card cancelled 6 months prior. I suppose I was okay with it, as it was preferable to a rejected charge, but it was a bit unnerving that a cancelled card was still accepting charges.